# Add service reference на WCF сервис с SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, .net, iis, wcf

Cервис на IIS

Открываю диалоговое окно Add Service Reference, вставляю адрес, откуда надо импортировать WSDL и получаю ошибку:

> Возникла ошибка при загрузке
> "https://212.112.97.194:7777/Service1.svc".
> Сбой запроса с состоянием HTTP 403:
> Forbidden. Метаданные содержат
> неразрешимую ссылку:
> "https://212.112.97.194:7777/Service1.svc".
> Запрос HTTP запрещен для схемы
> проверки подлинности клиентов
> "Anonymous". Удаленный сервер
> возвратил ошибку: (403) Запрещено. If
> the service is defined in the current
> solution, try building the solution
> and adding the service reference
> again.

Cертификаты сервера и клиента созданы, подписаны и через браузер веб-сервис доступен.
Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 1):

На сервере у сервиса присутствует данные строки в Web.config-е

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

?